# How to create a folder & a project under it with Deployment Manager (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

In a single Deployment Manager template, how do I create a new **folder** and a new **project** underneath it?  The problem is that the **reference** to the folder includes a `name` in the format `folders/123456`, but the project requires a `parent` field in the format `{'type': 'folder', 'id': 123456}`.  Using a `$(ref.new-folder.name)` won't work for the ID field in the `parent` record for the new project.

It feels like I need to do string manipulation on the `$(ref.new-folder.name)` like this:

```py
# DOES NOT WORK
# but if it did, I could extract the numeric id from 'folders/123456'
parent_id = '$(ref.new-folder.name)'.replace('folders/', '')
```

But, of course, that won't work.

Here is my (non-working) attempt:

```py
# Template for new folder & new project

folder_resource = {
  'name': 'new-folder',
  'type': 'gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v2:folders',
  'properties': {
     'parent': 'organizations/99999',
     'displayName': 'new-folder'
  }
}

project_resource = {
  'name': 'new-project',
  'type': 'clouresourcemanager.v1.project',
  'metadata': { 'dependsOn': ['new-folder'] },
  'properties': {
     'name': 'new-project',
     'parent': {
        'type': 'folder',
        # HERE it is -- the problem!
        'id': '$(ref.new-folder.name)'
     }
  }
}

return { 'resources': [folder_resource, project_resource] }
```

So, to reiterate, I'm getting hung-up on extracting the **numeric folder id** from the reference to the folder's `name`.  The `name` is in the format `folders/123456` but I just need the `123456` part to use in the `parent` field for the new project.

This question is specific to folder & project creation, but a more generalized question would be: is there a way to do string-manipulation on the value of references?

Comment: Howdy ... I get the feeling that Templates in Deployment Manager will give you the "scripting" that you want.  This can either be in Jinja or Python ... see https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template

Comment: Normally, they do! The problem is that I can't operate on $(ref.resource.value) -- the expansion of that variable at runtime prevents performing string operations on it.

Comment: Like you mentioned, there is no clean reference to be made here. And since the python functions finish before the DM template is applied, you can't use python functions to fetch the folder name to pass to a python function.

Comment: This seems like a poor design choice. I'd recommend opening a feature request to have either the project API (for the `resourceID` field) or the folder API to be updated so that they can work more in line with what we'd expect for automation

Comment: same problem, opened an issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/525

Answer (score 1):

For creating and managing folders document [a] might be helpful and folder name must meet the following requirements:

1. The name may contain letters, digits, spaces, hyphens and underscores.
2. The folder's display name must start and end with a letter or digit.
3. The name must be 30 characters or less.
4. The name must be distinct from all other folders that share its parent.

To create a folder:

Folders can be created with an API request.

The request JSON:

```
request_json= '{
display_name: "[DISPLAY_NAME]"
}'
```

The Create Folder curl request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" \
-d "$request_json" \
https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v2/folders?parent=[ORGANIZATION_NAME]
```

Where:

-[DISPLAY_NAME] is the new folder's display name, for example "My Awesome Folder."

-[ORGANIZATION_NAME] is the name of the organization under which you're creating the 
 folder, for example organizations/123.

The Create Folder response:

```
{
  "name": "operations/fc.123456789",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.resourcemanager.v2.FolderOperation",
    "displayName": "[DISPLAY_NAME]",
    "operationType": "CREATE"
  }
}
```

The Get Operation curl request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" \
https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/operations/fc.123456789
```

The Get Operation response:

```
{
      "name": "operations/fc.123456789",
      "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.resourcemanager.v2.FolderOperation",
        "displayName": "[DISPLAY_NAME]",
        "operationType": "CREATE"
      },
      "done": true,
      "response": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.resourcemanager.v2.Folder",
        "name": "folders/12345",
        "parent": "organizations/123",
        "displayName": "[DISPLAY_NAME]",
        "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
        "createTime": "2017-07-19T23:29:26.018Z",
        "updateTime": "2017-07-19T23:29:26.046Z"
      }
    }
```

**Configuring access to folders**

SetsIamPolicy sets the access control policy on a folder, replacing any existing policy. The resource field should be the folder's resource name, for example, folders/1234.

```
request_json= '{
   policy: {
     version: "1",
     bindings: [
       {
         role: "roles/resourcemanager.folderEditor",
         members: [
           "user:email1@example.com",
           "user:email2@example.com",
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

The curl request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" \
   -d "$request_json" \
   https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v2/[FOLDER_NAME]:setIamPolicy
```

Where:

-[FOLDER_NAME] is the name of the folder whose IAM policy is being set, for example folders/123.

**Creating a project in a folder**

```
 request_json= ‘{
      name: “[DISPLAY_NAME]”, projectId: “[PROJECT_ID]”, parent: {id: [PARENT_ID], type: [PARENT_TYPE] }
   }’
```

The curl request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" \
   -d "$request_json" \
   https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects
```

Where:

-[PROJECT_ID] is id of the project being created, for e.g., my-awesome-proj-123.

-[DISPLAY_NAME] is the display name of the project being created.

-[PARENT_ID] is the id of the parent being created under, for e.g. 123

-[PARENT_TYPE] is the type of the parent, like “folder” or “Organization”

When we create a reference to a resource, we also create a dependency between resources, document [b] might be helpful for this.

[a]-https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders
[b]-https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/use-references

Comment: Thanks for that!  However, I'm trying to solve this problem specifically for Deployment Manager -- without using gcloud scripts.

Comment: I was looking for a workaround using deployment manager but unfortunately unable to get any. Seems it is better to create a feature request using: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers